# can't write to file using print

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $vmstat, "/usr/bin/vmstat 1 2>&1 |");
open(my $foo, ">", "foo.txt") or die "can't open it for write";

while(<$vmstat>) {
   print "get ouput from vmstat and print it to foo.txt ...\n";
   print $foo $_;
}
```

when I run the above code, nothing wrong happend.but after I press ctr-c to quit, nothing in the foo.txt. could any of you tells me why does this happen? thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that you get the "get output..." text to console? If $vmstat never gives data it could be the cause. Your shebang is also wrong (shouldn't have a space after the `#!`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the output is being buffered and you are not being patient enough. Try this extra line of code:

```
open(my $foo, ">foo.txt") or die "can't open it for write";
select $foo; $| = 1; select STDOUT;
```

Comment: better: `use IO::File (); open …; $foo->autoflush(1);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with this line:

```
opne(my $foo, ">" "foo.txt") or die "can't open it for write";
```

First of all, `open` is misspelled.  Also, you have two strings next to each other, with nothing separating them.  Try this:

```
open(my $foo, ">foo.txt") or die "can't open it for write";
```

Also, if that doesn't fix your problem, double check that you (or the user this runs as) has write access to the file foo.txt.

Comment: @pkeaeding: thanks for indicate me the edit error I've made. but it's definitely not the solution for the problem and I do can write the file ...

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: "opne" instead of "open".

Also, to read from processes, you must put a pipe at the end:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $vmstat, "/usr/bin/vmstat 1 5 2>&1 |") or die "error";
open(my $foo, ">foo.txt") or die "can't open it for write";

while(<$vmstat>) {
    print "get ouput from vmstat and print it to foo.txt ...\n";
    print $foo $_;
}
```

Comment: first of all, thanks again tells me the typo I've made, anyway I've fix the two you've mentioned. then, the reason why I downgrade your answer is that instead of while(), while(<$vmstat>) should be used ...

Comment: don't know why the negative vote, since my code works. :)
In any case, by opening processes with a pipe at the beginning you
can write to them. And with a pipe at the end you can read from them.

Comment: You're right. I used the less then and greater than signs instead
of using their respective html entities.
That's why the file descriptor inside wasn't visible.
Never mind the vote, glad I could help.

Comment: @Haiyuan: you can retract your vote now that sespindola has edited it. @sespindola: please format your code correctly in future; HTML entities are not parsed inside code blocks. (Indent by four characters, or highlight the area and click the binary icon.)  There is rarely a need to use HTML anywhere in a post; please see the guide: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help